# Get_It Flutter Multiple Abstract Class Registration

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection

We are using the package get_it:^7.1.3 for dependency injection.
I want to register some classes with the same abstract class (like they were interfaces) and get them like:

`List<AbstractLass> allClassesWhichImplementAbstractClass=di.sl.get<AbstractLass>();`

Therefore I'd like to register it the following way:

```
  sl.registerLazySingleton<AbstractLass>(() =>
  AbstractLassImpl1());
  sl.registerLazySingleton<AbstractLass>(() =>
  AbstractLassImpl2());
```

But as I do that, I'll get an exception :

```
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Object/factory with  type AbstractLass is already registered inside GetIt. )
```

There is another solution where I register just the implementation the following way:

```
  sl.registerLazySingleton<AbstractLassImpl1>(() =>
  AbstractLassImpl1());
  sl.registerLazySingleton<AbstractLassImpl2>(() =>
  AbstractLassImpl2());
```

which works but then I would not access both by using their abstract class (if that is possible)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it by providing `instanceName` parameter like so:

```
sl.registerLazySingleton<AbstractClass>(() =>
  AbstractClassImpl1(), instanceName: 'implementation1');
sl.registerLazySingleton<AbstractClass>(() =>
  AbstractClassImpl2(), instanceName: 'implementation2');
```

And use it also with the same name included:

```
sl.get<AbstractClass>(instanceName: 'implementation1');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only register one object using `registerLazySingleton()` due to its Singleton behaviour.

If you want to register multiple interfaces with different implementation, try using `registerFactory()`, etc.

Comment: But then how do you get the instance that you want?